# Cannot make negative condition in htaccess work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I tried to write a rule for multilingual site. For example, www.hostname.com/fr & www.hostname.com/de are ok, but trying any other language tag should redirect to www.hostname.com/en.
www.hostname.com/it redirects to www.hostname.com/en, www.hostname.com/es redirects to www.hostname.com/en etc...

I succeed to make some rules in a "positive" way, but each time I add a ! to create a negative rule, it doesn't work.

For example :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hostname.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?([a-z]{2})/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(fr|de)/?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.hostname.com/en [L,R=301]
```

This code redirects everything to hostname.com/en. I want that only tag different than fr et de redirect to en. So I tried :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hostname.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?([a-z]{2})/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(fr|de)/?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.hostname.com/en [L,R=301]
```

Just added a !. But it doesn't work, URL are never redirected. I've probably missed something in writing rules...

Comment: Your negative rule works exactly as expected when I test at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be.  However, you will have a rewrite loop on the `en`.  You probably need `!^/?(fr|de|en)/?$` Also, the REQUEST_URI should always begin with `/` so the `?` to make it optional isn't necessary.

Comment: I agree with Michael Berkowski. You're suffering an infinite loop because the /en path is being redirected to itself. The `L` flag in mod_rewrite does not behave as a  lot of people think. Even a rewritten URL has to go through the httpd.conf or .htaccess directives from the top, and the `L` flag does not stop this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split this into two rules. The first rule handles `fr`, `de` and `en`. It doesn't rewrite anything and passes the request unchanged to Apache. If this doesn't match, the second rule handles everything else

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:fr|de|en)
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/(.*)$ /en/$1 [R,L]
```

Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.